# How to find the button on the entered position by user and change it's color in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600
running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

def drawGrid():
    for y in range (50):
        for x in range (50):
            pygame.draw.rect (screen , ( 0 , 0 , 255 ) , ( ( x * 20 ) , ( y * 20 ) , 20 , 20 ) , 1)
        for event in pygame.event.get():    
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pos = event.pos
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    drawGrid()
    pygame.display.update()
```

So I basically create a grid and I also figured out how to get the position at which the user clicks the screen. What I want to do now is that using the position which the user has clicked, I want to find the corresponding button at that location. Once I find which button corresponds to the position at which the user clicked, I want to then change the color of the button to something else.

---

Edit:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600
running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

cell_size = 20
size_x = width // cell_size
size_y = height // cell_size
grid = [[False for y in range(size_y)] for x in range(size_x)]

def drawGrid():
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for y in range (size_y):
        for x in range (size_x):
            # rectangle and color of cell
            cell_rect = pygame.Rect(x * 20, y * 20, 20, 20)           
            cell_color = (0, 0, 255)

            # change color of button if the mouse is on the button
            if cell_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                cell_color = (255, 255, 255)
            elif grid[x][y]:
                cell_color = (0, 255, 255)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, cell_color, cell_rect, 1)   

z = 0

while running and z < 2:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            cell_x, cell_y = event.pos[0] // cell_size, event.pos[1] // cell_size
            grid[cell_x][cell_y] = not grid[cell_x][cell_y]
            z += 1
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    drawGrid()
    pygame.display.update()
```

So basically what I want to do is that I want to stop clicking a rectangle in after two rectangles. So like if the user has already clicked two boxes (starting point and ending point), then I want to no longer add more boxes whenever the user clicks over a rectangle. I got it to work but the issue is that I only got it to work when two clicks are done the whole window closes. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never get the events (`pygame.event.get()`) multiple times in the application loop.

Use [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) to get the position of the mouse. Create a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object with the size of the cell and us [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to evaluate if the mouse is in the cell.

```py
def drawGrid():

    # get current mouse position
    mosue_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for y in range (50):
        for x in range (50):

            # rectangle and color of cell
            cell_rect = pygame.Rect(x * 20, y * 20, 20, 20)           
            cell_color = (0, 0, 255)

            # change color of button if the mouse is on the button
            if cell_rect.collidepoint(mosue_pos):
                cell_color = (255, 255, 255)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, cell_color, cell_rect, 1)
```

[image]

---

If you want to change the cell on click, then you have to create a grid of states:

```py
grid = [[False for y in range(size_y)] for x in range(size_x)]
```

Change the state of the cell when clicked on it:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    cell_x, cell_y = event.pos[0] // cell_size, event.pos[1] // cell_size
    grid[cell_x][cell_y] = not grid[cell_x][cell_y]
```

Set the color dependent on the state of the cell:

```py
if grid[x][y]:
    cell_color = (255, 255, 255)
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600
running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

cell_size = 20
size_x = width // cell_size
size_y = height // cell_size
grid = [[False for y in range(size_y)] for x in range(size_x)]

def drawGrid():

    for y in range(size_y):
        for x in range(size_x):

            # rectangle and color of cell
            cell_rect = pygame.Rect(x * 20, y * 20, 20, 20)           
            cell_color = (0, 0, 255)

            # change color of button if the mouse is on the button
            if grid[x][y]:
                cell_color = (255, 255, 255)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, cell_color, cell_rect, 1)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            cell_x, cell_y = event.pos[0] // cell_size, event.pos[1] // cell_size
            grid[cell_x][cell_y] = not grid[cell_x][cell_y]

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    drawGrid()
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

If you want to prevent to select cells, after 2 boxes have been clicked, then you have to evaluate the number of selected cells in the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event:

```py
z = 0
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if z < 2:

                cell_x, cell_y = event.pos[0] // cell_size, event.pos[1] // cell_size
                grid[cell_x][cell_y] = not grid[cell_x][cell_y]
                z += 1 if grid[cell_x][cell_y] else -1

    # [...]
```

Comment: I see! I didn't know about collidepoint() thank you! Also I want to sort of create a path finding algorithm so instead of just changing the color if the user's mouse is over the rectangle, I can manipulate it so that it changes only when its clicked. But thank you for this again!

Comment: also, if you don't mind can I ask you how you actually learn this stuff? Python is my first programming language I'm learning and I know the basics but again I just mostly learn by doing these type of projects. Do you have any like specific links or tips as to how to learn a programming language better or fully? Also I wouldn't mind a tip on reading the documention of something like pygame here where if I knew how to correctly read and use the documention I wouldn't probably be asking this. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: @jackbob 1. I've extended the answer. 2. Start at [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and [PyGame - tutorials](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials)

Comment: I have basically kinda fixed up how when two boxes are clicked I no longer want to check for any others, but the issue is that the fix I did causes the whole window to close. I extended the code I did in the question and my issue a little more clearly is also explained in the description of the question. And thanks for the python links I will check them out!

Comment: @jackbob No! Do not rewrite your Question! When you change the complete question, then my answer becomes useless. If you have a new Question, then  [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Anyway, I've extended the answer.

Comment: will keep in mind for next time! thank you for all the help once again!